# C# System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, lambda, moq

I get the above exception whenever I try running my unit test. It seems to have a problem specifically with the setup function for my service mock.

Now I understand that this requires some kind of abstraction. Do one or more of my classes need to be declared abstract or virtual? How exactly does it work? Any help would be appreciated.

The code is as follows:

```
 public class BaseService
 {
    public string GetData(string password)
    {
        string result = "";

        if (password.Equals("password") 
        {
             result = "granted";
        }

        return result;
    }
 }

 public class LookupService
 {
    private readonly BaseService baseService;

    public LookupService()
    {
        baseService = new BaseService();
    }

    public LookupService(BaseService base)
    {
        baseService = base;
    }

    public string GetCode(string password)
    {
        string returnString = baseService.GetData(password);

        return returnString;
    }
}

public class UnitTest_LookupService
{
    LookupService lookupService { get; set; }

    [Fact]
    public void moqTest()
    {
        Mock<BaseService> baseMock = new Mock<BaseService>();

        lookupService = new LookupService(baseMock.Object);

        baseMock.Setup(x => x.GetData("password")).Returns("granted");

        string result = lookupService.GetCode("password");

        Assert.Equal("granted", result);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you need the mock for? Your BaseService already returns "granted" if you pass it "password".

Comment: I hope this is example code, because it violates a heap of best practices regarding passwords.

Comment: Why, you don't test your passwords in code, and accept only the literal `password` for a password?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare GetData virtual if you want to mock it:

```cs
public class BaseService
{
    public virtual string GetData(string password)
    {
        string result = "";

        if (password.Equals("password") 
        {
             result = "granted";
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

But a much better idea is to declare an interface and mock that:

```cs
public interface IBaseService
{
    string GetData(string password);
}

public class BaseService : IBaseService
{
    public string GetData(string password)
    {
        string result = "";

        if (password.Equals("password") 
        {
             result = "granted";
        }

        return result;
    }
}
....
Mock<IBaseService> baseMock = new Mock<BaseService>();
lookupService = new LookupService(baseMock.Object);
```

But you should really think about what you are testing. There's not one bit of test code in what you are showing. You want to test your actual logic, not your mocks, they are just there to help you isolate the actual logic.

And the final comments:
Never store a password in clear text, store a salted and hashed value and compare that to the salted and hashed value of the user input.